# How to run a plugin in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have copied a sample Artifactory plugin which is a groovy file from git.
but i want to know how to run it. does it show in the GUI? or do i have to run it using some tool to check if its working. How to run groovy plugins in Artifactory. 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/download/attachments/46107593/samplePlugin_v4.groovy?version=1&modificationDate=1399538106000&api=v2

Answer (score 0):

The example plugin that you attached as a link is basically an example to all of the closers you have in Artifactory for triggering user plugins.

You should decide first what is the action that you need to do if it's execution or an event-based trigger.(For example, afterDownload).

You should really read the wiki page by JFrog on the User Plugins:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins